# How to calculate average of values with the same timestamp in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, sql-timestamp

i have the following table:

| date | value | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 | 5 |  |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 | 10 |  |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 | 5 |  |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 | 4 |  |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 | 5 |  |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 | 8 |  |

And i want to know how could i calculate the average of values with the same timestamp, like this:

| date | value | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 | 5 | 7,5 |
| 2021-04-07 18:00:00 | 10 | 7,5 |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 | 5 | 4,5 |
| 2021-04-07 18:02:00 | 4 | 4,5 |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 | 5 | 6,5 |
| 2021-04-07 18:03:00 | 8 | 6,5 |

I'm also wondering if it would be easier to calculate the average on a separate table so they won't repeat because there is more than one row with the same timestamp.
Hope someone can help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You want window AVG https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query:

`SELECT date, AVG(value) as avg_value FROM MyTable GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 2):

In an internal select, obtain the `avg` with the `group by date` . Then `join` the records whose `date` is equal to the internal select `date`.

```
SELECT t1.date,t2.value,t1.average 
FROM
 (SELECT date,AVG(Cast(value as Float)) as average
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY date) t1 JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
```

result: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=038352284d677a04c1525db88627b598)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(date AS DATE) as DateField, AVG(value) as avg_value
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       avg(value) over (partition by date) as timestamp_average
from t;
```